# How to render editor template for model property by property name

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

The end goal is to render an editor template, for a model property, known only at run time, that will not take it's value from the ViewBag.

`Html.Editor` will use the ViewBag value if the property names match. I don't want this and I hate this "feature".

I hope that this is possible somehow:

```
var propName = "MyProperty";
var expression = GiveMeTheExpression();
@Html.EditorFor(expression,"MyEditorTemplate")
```

If not this then some way of rendering an editor template without the viewbag values being used instead of the model's values. I'm totally fine with doing this, IF I CAN IGNORE THE VIEWBAG VALUES SOMEHOW:

```
@Html.Editor(propName, other, arguments)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to use Html.Partial with a custom ViewDataDictionary.

```
object knownAtRuntime = ViewBag.ObjectName; // Adapt to your solution
string templateName = String.Concat("EditorTemplates/", knownAtRuntime.GetType().Name);            

@Html.Partial(templateName, knownAtRuntime, new ViewDataDictionary(knownAtRuntime));
```

Note: I made this example simple to illustrate the core concept but you can of course extend it to read [UIHintAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.aspx) etc if you like.

Note 2: You may also want to copy values from Html.ViewData to the new ViewDataDictionary to keep your modelstate etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this ?

```
@Html.EditorFor(x=>x.SomePropertyName)
```

Assuming `SomePropertyName` is the name of a Property of your Model which is strongly typed to your view.

Comment: "...render an editor template, for a model property, known only at run time..."

Answer (score 0):

**Shyju** taking about strongly typed object, if I understand you correctly, you need something like: [asp.net mvc 3 and dynamic view generation](http://forums.asp.net/post/4477175.aspx)

Comment: I understand what that is doing and yes, I'm doing something similar, but that doesn't address my question. In that example, they know they property type at design time. My application doesn't know the type until runtime.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the @Html.Editor() method with property name as string and to use ViewBag keys that are very unlikely to be found on the model object.

Not ideal, but should work well.